# For what real values of $a,b$ does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^{an+b} $ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For what real values of $a$ and $b$ does $$\sum_{n=0}^{∞} n^{an+b} $$ converge?

If I set $a=0$ and $b<1$ I get the convergent $p$-series, but I highly doubt that's all the values.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: if $a > 0$ the series diverges because the terms get large.

Comment: If $a<0$, this converges trivially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b$ be some fixed real number. If $a>0$, then when $n>\frac{1-b}{a}$ we see that $an+b>1$. So for all numbers $n>\max\{\frac{1-b}{a},1\}$, we have that

$$
n^{an+b} >1
$$

so the sum must diverge.

On the other hand, if $a<0$ we similarly find that for $n>\max\{\frac{2+b}{-a},1\}$, we have that $an+b<-2$ and

$$
n^{an+b} < n^{-2}.
$$

The sum

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
$$ is convergent so now your sum must converge.

You noticed that the case $a=0$ and $b<-1$ is convergent by the $p$-series test. So consider $a=0$ and $b\geq -1$. Then, you have (by term by term comparison)

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{b} \geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty.
$$

The latter series is the harmonic series and famously diverges.